# Symfony form field of type checkbox is always interpreted as true when it is contained in request

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I've a own concept of validating parts of a form. It relies on the fact, that every property of the entity has its own validation group, p.e.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration, "validation_height"}, message="Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Angabe und geben Sie Ihre korrekte Körpergröße ein.
")
     */
    protected $height;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, nullable=false, columnDefinition="ENUM('male', 'female')")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration", "validation_gender"}, message="Bitte geben Sie Ihr Geschlecht an.")
     */
    protected $gender;

    /**
     * @Assert\True(groups={"registration", "validation_agreeTerms"}, message="Bitte bestätigen Sie die AGB und Datenschutzbestimmungen.")
     */
    protected $agreeTerms;
```

With form type

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('email', NULL, array('label' => 'E-Mail'))
            ->add('username', NULL, array('label' => 'Benutzername'))
            [...]
            ->add('agreeTerms', 'checkbox', array('label' => false))
        ;
```

In my Ajax controller I'm setting the validation groups dynamically, so there is an Javascript function that forces sending of every visible form field (including checkbox that aren't checked) - a web browser would not sent unchecked checkboxes by default.

```
class AjaxController extends BaseController
{
    protected function validateRegistrationFields($request) {
        $return = array();
        $groups = array();
        $data = $request->get('registration', array());
        foreach (array_keys($data) as $field) $groups[] = 'validation_' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $field);

        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->createUser();

        $form_type = new RegistrationType();
        $form = $this->createNamedForm('registration', $form_type, $user, array(
            'validation_groups' => $groups,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
        $form->bind($request);
        if (!$form->isValid()) $return = $this->getFormErrors($form, true, 'registration');
        return $return;
    }
```

So with use of my Javascript function I can be sure, that `registration[agreeTerms]` is contained in `POST` request and the related validation group `validation_agreeTerms` is set. The problem is, the value of `$agreeTerms` is always `true` when submitting form with use of JS function. I believe this relies on Symfony behaviour, which supposes, that a form field of type `checkbox`, that is contained in request, regardless of the value, is true. When submitting the form by real browser `POST` (and not by Ajax), the checkbox is not contained in `POST` data and all is fine.

An example `POST` looks like

```
registration[email]: example@example.com
registration[username]: sunny123
registration[agreeTerms]:
```

As you can see, `agreeTerms` is submitted with empty data, because it is not checked, but Symfony seems to convert it `true` when binding request to form, only based on the fact, that this field/property is contained in `POST` data.
Is there a way to get a submitted checkbox with an empty value in `POST` to be interpreted as `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PreBind listener form can be useful here. [About Form Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). 
It seems possible to change the data before binding (`$form->bind()`). Consider the example:

```
class SetDataAgreeTermedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_BIND => 'preBind');
    }

    public function preBind(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $fdata = $event->getData();

        if ((boolean)$fdata['agreeTerms'] !== true) {
            unset($fdata['agreeTerms']);
        }

        $event->setData($fdata);
}
```

Comment: At this point of code, `$value` is `true` already, so no chance to check or modify inside setter method.

Comment: Oh, got it.. I think the form binding sets the $value.. It's possible to change the data before.. check the version in the edited answer.